# R: Transforming a dataset with the variables "country" and "x" to an adjacency matrix by recoding x

Tags: r, social-networking, data-manipulation

suppose I have following data set `CL` in R:

```
country    x
USA        7
Canada     7
Bahamas    6
Cuba       1
Haiti      2
```

Now, what I intend to do is to create an adjacency matrix where the countries are the nodes, and the strength of the ties are the absolute difference of the values of `x`. For example, the tie between the Bahamas `(x=6)` and Cuba `(x=1)` would have a strength of `6-1=5`.

Thus, here the network matrix would look like this:

```
country USA Canada Bahamas Cuba Haiti
USA      0    0       -1    -6    -5
Canada   0    0       -1    -6    -5
Bahamas  1    1        0    -5    -4
Cuba     6    6        5     0     4
Haiti    5    5        4    -1     0
```

I have been struggling with this problem for quite a long time, and I just can't come to a decent approach to solve this. My actual data set consists of 150 countries, so it would be really troublesome to do this in Excel. So, does anyone have, how to do this in R? Thank you very much!

Here the R code for reproduction:

```
country<- c("USA", "Canada", "Bahamas", "Cuba", "Haiti")
x<- c(7,7,6,1,2)

CL<- data.frame(country=country, x=x)
```

Comment: I think your `Cuba <-> Haiti` relation should be `1` and `-1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grid <- expand.grid(x, x)
grid$strength <- grid$Var1 - grid$Var2
mat <- matrix(grid$strength, nrow=5, ncol=5, byrow=TRUE)
```

Comment: Well done on your first answer. You may want to include a bit more explanation about this, and provide a printout of the results to make it stronger.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `dist` function in base R:

```
dist_mat = as.matrix(dist(CL$x, diag = TRUE, upper = TRUE))

dist_mat[upper.tri(dist_mat)] = -dist_mat[upper.tri(dist_mat)]

dimnames(dist_mat) = list(country, country)
```

**Result:**

```
        USA Canada Bahamas Cuba Haiti
USA       0      0      -1   -6    -5
Canada    0      0      -1   -6    -5
Bahamas   1      1       0   -5    -4
Cuba      6      6       5    0    -1
Haiti     5      5       4    1     0
```

Note that the `Cuba <-> Haiti` relation is actually incorrect, since `dist` returns absolute distances. To get around that, you can use the following method:

```
dist_mat2 = -(outer(x, x, "-"))

dimnames(dist_mat2) = list(country, country)
```

**Result:**

```
        USA Canada Bahamas Cuba Haiti
USA       0      0      -1   -6    -5
Canada    0      0      -1   -6    -5
Bahamas   1      1       0   -5    -4
Cuba      6      6       5    0     1
Haiti     5      5       4   -1     0
```

Equivalent to the `dist` method, you can also use:

```
dist_mat = abs(outer(x, x, "-"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfect! However, I didn't quite get your explanation why Cuba > Haiti is 1 in the dist method. Isn't -1 the absolute difference of Cuba (x=1) and Haiti (x=2)? In the other ties it seems to work perfectly...

Comment: @Vknkmpkt Yeah, I mentioned in my answer that the `dist` method doesn't quite work for your example since it only returns absolute distances (I was saying that my Cuba > Haiti relation is incorrect, not yours). The `outer` method works perfectly though and is much shorter than the accepted answer.